# why can't I run a ProgressDialog inside doInBackground method of AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am not able to run a `ProgressDialog` inside the `doInBackground` method of AsyncTask. It gives me the following error:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12986): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

And the error is on this line in the code:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(GalleryView.this, "Refresh", "Loading... please wait", true);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show the progressdialog in the onPreExecute method and dismiss it in the onPostExecute method.  These two methods run in the UI thread. The doInBackGround method runs in another thread.

Another possibility is to just show the progressdialog before you start the AsyncTask. Personally I like the option to use onPreExecute and onPostExecute. The progressdialog is then linked nicely to the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

As the doinbackground doesn't run on the ui thread so it cannot create UI elements. You should create the progress dialog before executing the AsyncTask.

Comment: Ok, this is what I am trying to do. I want to run the progressdialog on a piece of code. Once the code finishes, I dismiss the dialog and want to call AsyncTask to refresh my UI. I am not able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncTask` construct is about separating background and UI thread operations. Within `doInBrackground` you are not in the UI thread, so you cannot do UI related logic at all. The right place to do that is in the methods that run on the UI thread. I'm guessing for your particular case such place would be `onPreExecute`.

Answer (score 1):

ProgressDialog is UI code, so it must happen on the event queue. AsyncTask runs off the event queue. You can do a progress dialog as such:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = activity.findViewById(progressBarID);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true)
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> aTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
 @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //Do your operations here
   return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Wrap up anything here, like closing the popup.
 }
};
aTask.execute((Void)null);
```

Comment: Ok. Now I am having trouble refreshing my GalleryView with new items. I am calling my progress dialog in onPreExecute and it runs fine. In doInBackground, I am calling my handler to update the Adapter for GalleryView and so also the GalleryView itself with new items in the Adapter. But the gallery refreshes only if I move the items in it out of the screen. Any help?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Hmm. Can we see some code? Maybe start a new question. That way you'll be more likely to to attract people who know the answer.